# RobotFramework: Converting month from date to numerical format

Tags: datetime, robotframework, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to convert a date in the following format: `26 Sep 2019 11:56` to the below format `26-09-2019 11:56` with no success.
I am using convert date in such way:

```
${date} convert date ${date} date_format=%d %b %Y %H:%m result_format=%d-%m-%Y %H:%m
```

I get an error:

> Valueerror: unconverted data remains: 2

Could you please assist me on this?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `minutes` parameter must be uppercase `%M`. In your case, it would be:

```
${converted_date}  convert date  ${date}  date_format=%d %b %Y %H:%M  result_format=%d-%m-%Y %H:%M
```

More info: 
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Date%20formats